# Why does getting random numbers using Chainlink take more than 30 seconds?

Tags: blockchain, oracles, chainlink, randomness, vrf

I'm writing an article and I'm using Chainlink VRF in one part. Theoretically, this is a two-transaction process, as it is impossible to storethe cryptographic proof on the blockchain and read the result at the same time. The estimated time to get random numbers is 30 seconds, right? For the two transactions that need to be executed. The problem is that it is taking more to return the random number. How could I justify this time?

If it were 40 seconds, maybe I could overlook it. But I just did some tests and the time was 59 seconds, so I have to justify this time. Is it only due to the Ethereum blockchain (Kovan in this case) congestion?

Comment: It's the first time I use VRF but it's already been almost 4 hours and my requests are still showing as pending in the Subscription Manager. I'm using Rinkeby.

Comment: @AntaoAlmada Check if all the components are OK. Does the contract have enough LINK? I´m doing some tests at this moment in Kovan and everything is perfect. It takes around 45-50 seconds.

Comment: If you want a fast blockchain, do not use EVM chains. Use Near, Solana. EVM just cannot do it any faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is correct. The delay is due to needing multiple transactions stored on-chain. The Kovan testnet generally takes around ~1 min to return a random number.